# Only show warnings from some folders in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I am working in a larger Java codebase in eclipse, which currently issues around 7000 warnings. However I am working in rather isolated parts, in a few specific source folders and namespaces. I would like eclipse to only show warnings for my modules in the Problems tab, and not for the entire codebase. Currently it shows the first 100 warnings which are not related to my modules. Is this possible?

**Update**
Thanks for all the nice answers. Updated the question a bit to make it clear that I am talking about multiple, albeit a rather small number, of folders and namespaces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Problems view there is a downward pointing triangle on the top right near the other view icons. Select that triangle and choose `Configure Contents...` from the menu. See below:

[image: Configure Contents in Problem View]

You can apply various configurations to control what elements show. I have the following configurations:

[image: Configure Contents Dialog]

[image: Configure Contents Dialog]

Notice that both of those configurations have the "On selected element and its children" scope selected. This will only show problems related to the file in the editor or package selected in the package view for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new "Working Set" and limit the warnings to the scope of the "Working set".
To change the scope of your Problems-Tab select the "view-menu" (little triangle) and choose "configure contents" there you find various options to configure the scope.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you activate **[Mylyn](http://eclipse.org/mylyn/)** on your project (in a [task-focused interface)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn_User_Guide#Task-Focused_Interface), you can, in a task specifc context, have the problems view filtered to show only warnings relevant for your current "context".

Or you can **[configure then content of a problems view](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#tips_problemsview)** in order to display only the warnings/errors for the selected element.

[image: configure content]

[image: selected element]

Answer (score 1):

You can limit warning to the selected resource(s), see problem view configuration (by clicking on the small triangle on the upper right of the view).

[image: Problem view configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Right now the best possible way is to declare a working set and configure the Problems View to show the contents only from that working set.

A better solution is (probably) coming directly from JDT. See this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=220928) for more details.